# Значение Nothing в цикле, когда должен быть Range

Tags: excel, vba

Ниже код, открывает листы из выбранной папки в рабочей книге, потом мне нужно каждый лист отформатировать, и нужно с конца таблицы удалить 8 строк, для этого я пытаюсь найти самую первую удаляемую строку, в ней всегда будет значение "б/с" и, начиная с нее, пытаюсь удалить вниз 8 строк, но выдает ошибку Run Time Error 91. Тк в цикле, в котором редактируются таблицы, переменная addss принимает значение Nothing, а по идеи должна быть Range. Помогите люди добрые

```
Sub FileList()
    Dim V As String
    Dim BrowseFolder As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select folder"
        .Show
        V = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    BrowseFolder = CStr(V)

    ListFilesInFolder BrowseFolder
End Sub


Private Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal SourceFolderName As String)
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SourceFolder As Object
    Dim FileItem As Object

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.getfolder(SourceFolderName)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Set importWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileItem)
        Sheets().Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        importWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Next FileItem

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Delete

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook


    For Each ws In wbCurrent.Worksheets
        Dim iR As Long
        Dim addss As Range

        ws.Cells.MergeCells = False

        Set addss = Columns("A:A").Find(What:="б/с")
        MsgBox TypeName(addss)  - выведет Nothing, а должен Range
        iR = addss.Row + 7 - соответственно из-за типа данных ошибка
        Range(Cells(addss, 1), Cells(iR, 1)).Delete 

        ws.Rows("21").Delete
        ws.Rows("11").Delete
        ws.Rows("1:9").Delete

ws.Range("W1,V1,T1,S1,P1,M1,L1,K1,H1,G1,F1,D1,C1,A1").EntireColumn.Delete

    Next ws

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Чё тут помогать-то? Вас не учили - сперва дефиниции, потом код? Кроме пееропределения динамичечских массивов, конечно... что делает `Dim addss As Range` в СЕРЕДИНЕ кода? Это то, что сразу в глаза бросается... И вообще - освойте трассировку и выполнение по шагам.

Comment: @Akina, все равно не работает, ничего не поменялось. Какой хреновый с вас помощник :)

Comment: Если Вас будут лечить по фотографии или по описанию симптомов - Вы будете обижаться на результат, буде не вылечат? Я уж не говорю о публикации всего, необходимого для хотя бы воспроизведения проблемы - но хотя бы минимальную методику можно было сделать? модельный какой-нить файл, с единственным модулем, к которому надо создать в каталоге пару текстовых файлов с заданным содержимым, например... В данном конкретном случае одних симптомов - мало. Причина может быть какой угодно - вплоть до кривой библиотеки или ещё какой косины конкретно на Вашей рабстанции.

Comment: @Akina, можете скопипастить данный код в эксель и в рабочем листе в ячейке написать б/с, у вас будет тоже самое)

Comment: Открыл новую книгу (1 лист), прописал А1:А3 (в А2 "б/с", в остальные ноль). Положил в c:\tmp два XLS файла по 1 листу. Запустил `FileList` в режиме трассировки. Скормил диалогу каталог. Cкопировал листы в книгу. Косяк 1 - `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Delete` хотел удалить первый лист с внесёнными данными, я запретил. Далее - обе строки с комментами выполнились корректно. Тип переменных верный, значение верное. Косяк в следующей строке `Range(Cells(addss, 1), Cells(iR, 1)).Delete` - от Range берётся default property, который Value, отсель ошибка, надо не `addss`, а `addss.Row`. Пока стоп.

Comment: Далее. Заменил. Ок, ячейки удалились, есссно со сдвигом влево. Ну а дальше непонятная вакханалия из 4 удалений... в общем, выполнение прервал. Имхо все косяки выявлены. Если у тебя код трассируется иначе - описывай, как выполняешь, как трассируешь, в чём различия.

Comment: @Akina решил проблему обычным указателем на активный лист
Set addss = ws.Columns("B:B").Find(What:="б/с")

Comment: Это было ПЕРВОЕ, что я Вам сказал ещё в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1060636/229437 - *К коду претензий нет.  Проблема в том, что **не указан как минимум лист**, и Columns указывает в небеса...*.

Comment: Дубликат вопроса? [Удаление строк VBA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1060693/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-vba)

Comment: *решил проблему обычным указателем на активный лист Set addss = ws.Columns* - не в этом проблема, уж поверьте. Столбец (строка, диапазон...) без указания родителя по умолчанию является подчиненным объектом АКТИВНОГО листа. А лист *ws* точно активен во время поиска значения?